# Using JQuery / AJAX to display XML Content in WordPress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, xml-parsing

I've been using variations of the following script to pull event information from our calendar's XML feed and display it in html pages:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../../../evanced/lib/eventsxml.asp?dm=exml&nd=14&fe=1&alltime=1",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParserFeatured,
        error: function(){alert("We're sorry. Something didn't load correctly.");}
    });
});
function xmlParserFeatured(xml) {
    $(xml).find("item").each(function () {
        var xml_image           = $(this).find('imagepath').text();
        var xml_imagetext       = $(this).find('imagetext').text();
        var xml_title           = $(this).find('title').text();
        var xml_date            = $(this).find('date').text();
        var xml_time            = $(this).find('time').text();
        var xml_endtime         = $(this).find('endtime').text();
        var xml_location        = $(this).find('location').text();
        var xml_link            = $(this).find('link').text();
        var xml_description     = $(this).find('description').text();
        var xml_signup          = $(this).find('signup').text();
        var xml_eventtype           = $(this).find('prieventtype').text();
        var hasImage            = xml_image != "" && xml_image != "";
        var hasDate             = xml_date != "";
        var noEndTime           = xml_time != "" && xml_endtime == "";
        var hasEndTime          = xml_time != "" && xml_endtime != "";
        var hasLink             = xml_link != "";
        var hasDescription      = xml_description != "";
        var hasLocation         = xml_location != "";
        var hasSignUp           = xml_signup == "1";
        var eventType           = xml_eventtype == "Outreach" || xml_eventtype == "Teen" || xml_eventtype == "Youth";
        var content = ((eventType) ? "<div class='article " + xml_eventtype + "'>" : "<div class='article Adult'>") +
            ((hasImage) ? "<img class='article' src='" + xml_image + "' alt='" + xml_imagetext + "' />" : "")
            + "<p class='article_heading'>" + ((hasLink) ? "<a href='" + xml_link + "'>" + xml_title + "</a></p>" : "<p class='article_heading'>" + xml_title + "</p>") 
            + "<p class='article_subheading'>" + xml_date + ((hasEndTime) ?  " from " + xml_time + " to " + xml_endtime : "") + ((noEndTime) ? " at " + xml_time : "") + ((hasLocation) ? "<br />Location: " + xml_location + "</p>" : "") 
            + ((hasDescription) ? "<p>" + xml_description + "</p>" : "") 
            + ((hasSignUp) ? "<p><a href='" + xml_link + "'>Register Online</a>.</p>" : "") 
            + "<div style='clear: both; height: 1px;'></div></div>";
        $(".event_list").append(content);
});}
```

We're in the process of moving our site to WordPress and I haven't been able to get this to work on any WP pages. My questions are a.) Should this be able to work in WordPress and b.) Is there another / different / better way to get the same results in WordPress? Most of what I've been able to find on the web discusses importing XML feeds as blog posts, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up scrapping this in favor of a simpler solution. Decided to only use nodes required to be populated and went with a php solution instead.

```
<?php
$url = "/evanced/lib/eventsxml.asp?dm=exml&nd=7&fe=1&alltime=1";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach($xml->item as$item)
    {
        echo "<div class='main-cal-event main-cal-event-".$item->prieventtype."'>";
        echo "<p><span class='event-title'><a href='".$item->link."'>".$item->title."</a></span><br />";
        echo "<span class='event-date'>".$item->date." from ".$item->time." to ".$item->endtime."</span><br />";
        echo "<span class='event-desc'>".$item->description."</span></p>";
        echo "<div class='fix'></div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you tried XSL to convert your XML into HTML?

Anyway, it's a JavaScript solution, so it has nothing to do with Wordpress, which is server-side.

1) Are you sure the HTML document created by Wordpress has at least one element with 'event_list' class? That doesn't seem to be a standard WP class, maybe you forgot about it.

2) Did you change your site's domain on the moving? JavaScript served by 1 domain sometimes can't send requests to other domain.

Comment: I haven't tried XSL and know very little about it. Will that allow me to display only selected nodes from the feed and disregard the coding for those nodes when they're empty? Not all events have end times / registration links, etc. As for the event_list class, I manually inserted it into a template in my child theme. It was displayed in the source code and my <noscript> escape appeared with JS turned off. Same when I coded it into the page content. The WP install is a folder on the same server as the calendar, but I suspect WP might not be finding the xml link. All my URL variations failed.

Comment: I even tried creating a small sample xml document and included it in the same folder as the above script.